# MVC variables not displaying in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, parent-child

I have 4 related classes which I am attempting to display information on but the value of the bottom level class attributes are not being displayed in the view despite the value being available when debugging it is never being transferred to the page my code is as follows:

**CONTROLLER**

```
// GET: MarketMessages
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var test = db.MarketMessage.Where(m => m.messageType == "300S")
    .Include(m => m.messageType300S
    .Select(mt => mt.Meter
    .Select(r => r.RegisterLevelInformation )))
    .ToList();

    return View(test);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.messageType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VersionNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarketTimestamp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TxRefNbr)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recipient)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.alertFlag)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fileName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDeleted)
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).FirstOrDefault())
            {
                @Html.Display(m.SerialNumber)
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MarketMessageID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MarketMessageID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MarketMessageID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**MODEL TOP LEVEL**

```
namespace BillingEngine.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("MarketMessage")]
    public partial class MarketMessage
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public MarketMessage()
        {
            messageType300 = new HashSet<messageType300>();
            messageType300S = new HashSet<messageType300S>();
            messageType300W = new HashSet<messageType300W>();
            messageType305 = new HashSet<messageType305>();
        }

        public int MarketMessageID { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string messageType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime MarketTimestamp { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string TxRefNbr { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Sender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Recipient { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string alertFlag { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string fileName { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType300> messageType300 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType300S> messageType300S { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType300W> messageType300W { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType305> messageType305 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MODEL LEVEL 2**

```
namespace BillingEngine.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class messageType300S
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public messageType300S()
        {
            Meter = new HashSet<Meter>();
            UsageFactor = new HashSet<UsageFactor>();
        }

        public int messageType300SID { get; set; }

        public int MarketMessageID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(11)]
        public string MPRN { get; set; }

        [StringLength(35)]
        public string MPBR { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string NetworkReferenceNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string LoadProfileCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string DUoSGroup { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string MeterPointStatusCode { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReadDate { get; set; }

        public virtual MarketMessage MarketMessage { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Meter> Meter { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UsageFactor> UsageFactor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MODEL LEVEL 3**

```
namespace BillingEngine.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("Meter")]
    public partial class Meter
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Meter()
        {
            RegisterLevelInformation = new HashSet<RegisterLevelInformation>();
        }

        public int MeterID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string MeterCategoryCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(9)]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string MeterLocationCode { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType300ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType300SID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType300WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType303RID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType305ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType306ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType306WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType307ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType307WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType310ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType310WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType320ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType320WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType341ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType342ID { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType300 messageType300 { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType300S messageType300S { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType300W messageType300W { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType305 messageType305 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RegisterLevelInformation> RegisterLevelInformation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MODEL LEVEL 4**

```
namespace BillingEngine.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("RegisterLevelInformation")]
    public partial class RegisterLevelInformation
    {
        public int RegisterLevelInformationID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string MeterRegisterSequence { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string TimeslotCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string UOM_Code { get; set; }

        public decimal MeterMultiplier { get; set; }

        public decimal ReadingValue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string ReadReasonCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string ReadTypeCode { get; set; }

        public DateTime? PreviousReadDate { get; set; }

        public decimal Consumption { get; set; }

        public decimal EstimatedConsumption { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4)]
        public string ReadStatusCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        public string RegisterTypeCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public string PostDecimalDetails { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        public string PreDecimalDetails { get; set; }

        public int? MeterID { get; set; }

        public int? RemovedMeterRegisterID { get; set; }

        public int? NewMeterRegisterID { get; set; }

        public int? RetainedMeterRegisterID { get; set; }

        public virtual Meter Meter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are created foreach loop if you want to display only first item?
 @foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).FirstOrDefault())

Comment: I want to display the list but as a means of tracking if I could even output the first value I tried doing first or default, it finds it but it does not output it on the view for some reason

Comment: Change @Html.Display(m.SerialNumber) to @Html.DisplayFor(m.SerialNumber)

Comment: @AdilMammadov I think you mean `@Html.DisplayFor(x => m.SerialNumber)`.. DisplayFor needs an expression

Comment: You are positive all the desired data is in the test model? I wouldn't think those interior Selects are valid. I've always had to do what you are doing with a Group Join and return an Anonymous type wrapping the data.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid thanks for that it displays then for single meter but if I create a ToList() instead of .FirstOrDefault() how can I reference each meter within the list? as the same expression does not seem to be valid

Comment: @Jay Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're asking.  If you create a list like so:  `var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).ToList()` then that will go through each item in the list.. but if you do this: `var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).FirstOrDefault()` then you putting all of the `Meter`'s in a list then selecting the very first item in that list, so that will only give you 1 result

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid what I meant what if I call (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).ToList()) how can I list the details of multiple meters using a foreach in this context

Comment: @Jay check my updated answer, and let me know if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, no one else is going to *answer* from the comments, I will.

Try changing this:

```
<td>
    @foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).FirstOrDefault())
    {
        @Html.Display(m.SerialNumber)
    }
</td>
```

To:

```
<td>
    @foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).FirstOrDefault())
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.SerialNumber)
    }
</td>
```

> Html.Display => Returns HTML markup for each property in the object that is represented by a string expression.
>
> Html.DisplayFor => Returns HTML markup for each property in the object that is represented by the System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression.

**UPDATE:**

If you are looking into looping through each `Meter` using `ToList()` and then displaying details of each meter then can do this:

```
<td>
    @foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.SelectMany(y => y.Meter).ToList())
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(y => m.SerialNumber)
        @Html.DisplayFor(y => m.OtherPropertyDetail) 
        @Html.DisplayFor(y => m.AnotherPropertyDetail)
    }
</td>
```

You are going to have to use `SelectMany` since `Meter` is already of type `ICollection`.. so if you just use `Select` you will generate something along these lines `List<List<Meter>[]>`.. so `SelectMany` will flatten that out to just a `List<Meter>` which is what you are looking for.

Comment: see this is what I had initially thought but this code gives me the error ICollection<Meter> as if m is being set as the collection of meters and not the meter itself

Comment: @Jay what does the error specifically say?  when you debug, what is in `m` for the first loop?

Comment: Does Select itself not return an enumerable collection?

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. Select's return type is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Comment: any better way you can think of returning this other than iterating the count of the meters using variable counter?

Comment: @Jay not really, did you get it working or is it still giving you an error? If it is giving you an error, what is it *exactly*?

Comment: @foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).ToList())
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.FirstOrDefault().SerialNumber)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.FirstOrDefault().MeterID)

                @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.FirstOrDefault().RegisterLevelInformation.FirstOrDefault().TimeslotCode)
            }

Comment: This gives me the information for the first meter and the first information but I have still not worked out how to iterate through these

Comment: @Jay why are you using `FirstOrDefault`? With this logic, you will iterate through all of the `Meter`'s but you will only pull the details of the first `Meter`.. so just take out `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: your code that you gave me is not valid its returning a list of meters and not a single meter so the properties are not accessible

Comment: @Jay Okay I think I found the issue.. change `@foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).ToList())` to `@foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(y => y.Meter).ToList())`.. the reason why you can't access properties is because your `Select` is using the var `m` which is also the var that you are using to try and access individual properties.

Comment: m still remains as an icollection of meters so calling @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.MeterID) results in error as there is no meterid property for the ilcollection of meters

Comment: @Jay Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118644/discussion-between-bville-kid-and-jay).